# Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' socket.io, docker, nginx

Tags: nginx, websocket, socket.io, nginx-reverse-proxy

I currently have a socket.io server running on a Digital Ocean droplet on a docker container. the container was run with ports mapping localhost:8080 -> 8080. `docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080`. I'm running nginx for https, but when I try to connect to the server I get

> blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Here's my current nginx config.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com

    location /{
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

I've gotten it to work with a similar configuration in the past, but I can't recreate it. Nothing I've tried works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CORS-Preflight check will fail from your browser. Have a look here:

[Nginx. Blocked by CORS policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747209/nginx-blocked-by-cors-policy/60747893#60747893)